# What is fastcgi_index in nginx used for?

Tags: nginx, fastcgi

On many sites can be found this nginx `location` block :

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000
    fastcgi_index index.php
    ...
}
```

Given the [official documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_index) of `fastcgi_index`, it seems like it is used when requests end with `/`. However, it doesn't match the regular expression of the `location` block above? Am I missing something about the `fastcgi_index` directive?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You are right, if your nginx configuration (outside the `location` directive) has no `index` directive, then the `location` directive will never match and the `fastcgi_index` directive is useless.

If you have a line like this on your configuration

```
index index.php
```

then a request to `/` will create an internal redirect to `/index.php`, the `location` will match and fastcgi will be called. php-fpm will need a `SCRIPT_FILENAME` parameter that points to the file being executed. Normally, the configuration looks something like this:

```
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
```

`$fastcgi_script_name` contains the name of the matched script, so `fastcgi_index` is ignored.

There is at least one instance where `fastcgi_index` is useful and used: [when nginx and php-fpm are on different servers and nginx can't match the index.php file](http://mailman.nginx.org/pipermail/nginx/2008-November/008311.html).