# Sample PHP page on localhost shows a blank page

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

I follow [this guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8KBOqpHhN_c) to setup a sample WordPress site on my Linux machine.  The packages are changed to the newer `php7.2-gd`, `php7.2-curl`, and `libssh2-php`.  My `/etc/nginx/sites-available/davewordpress` file is as follow:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/wordpress;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~\.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

After creating the `davewordpress` link in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` and restarting `nginx` and `php7.2-fpm`, my `localhost` gives a blank page.  What have I done wrong?

Comment: add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); error_reporting(-1);` to your `index.php` file at the top and you should see what's causing the error

Comment: Also, consult your logs.

Comment: Where can I find the error logs?

Comment: Check your `nginx.conf` file on error log path setting. By default, it should be at `var/log/nginx/`. BTW, replace `try_files $uri =404;`, with `include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;`

Comment: Blank page could also caused by your WordPress permalink setting, what is your permalink setting?

Comment: @hcheung, the error log shows nothing about my request to `localhost`.  How do I check WP's permalink setting?

Comment: @hcheung, changing the file with `include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;` causes the page to download a file called `download` which contains `require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );`.  Any idea?

Comment: To check permalink setting, Login to wp-admin, click on Settings->Permalinks.

Comment: @hcheung, my `localhost` page doesn't even load.  I can't get to the `Settings` page.

Comment: Downloading file means the rewrite isn't work correctly. Replace `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;` with `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;`.

Comment: Actually, the download occurs when I incorrectly placed `include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;` under `location / {`.  Placing it under `location ~ \.php$ {` instead causes NginX to fail to restart.

Comment: OK, the NginX error log shows `"fastcgi_index" directive is duplicate in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled`.  How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I run into [this link](https://serverfault.com/questions/826403/wordpress-not-rendering-site) while searching for the solution, and it really helps by pointing to the `location ~ \.php$` block.  I comment out two lines and have it working.  That blocks now looks like this:

```
    location ~ \.php$ {     
    #try_files $uri =404;
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    #fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    }
```

Using `sudo nginx -t`, the first line reports this problem:

```
"try_files" directive is duplicate in /etc/nginx/snippets/fastcgi-php.conf:5
```

The second line reports this problem:

```
"fastcgi_index" directive is duplicate in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/u1804wordpress:27
```

Glad to finally figure it out.  I understand the first error.  However, can anybody explain to me the second one?

Comment: means in ````fastcgi-php.conf````, there is already the directive ````fastcgi_index```` defined, and you are redefining it in the ````location```` block.

Comment: For detailed information about ````fastcgi_index````, refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30802025/what-is-fastcgi-index-in-nginx-used-for